# NoMethodError in ProductCategoriesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to create a session. My action looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def prepare_cart
    session[:cart] = {} if session[:cart].empty?
  end
end
```

for this i am getting the error :

```
NoMethodError in ProductCategoriesController#index 
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Cant find out whats the probem. It worked well the first time. when i restated the browser, this error started appearing. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your session does not have :cart key to check emptiness in the first place.

try this:

```
session[:cart] ||= {}
```

Answer (score 0):

session[:cart] is nil so that you are getting nil error, Please check nil condition.